# JS dynamic change divs width in loop

Tags: javascript, css, charts, setinterval

I want to create simple bar chart with animated bars (width from 0 to final size).

I started from css transitions but opera and chrome sometimes have problems.

Now I try to use mechanism what I saw here:

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_progressbar.asp

using JS.

I have few "bar-areas":

```html
  <div id="chart-bars">
    <div class="chart-bar-area">
        <div class="chart-bar" data-percent="80"  ></div>

    </div>

        <div class="chart-bar-area">
        <div class="chart-bar" data-percent="60"   ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and JS code which works fine with one bar, but if I try to implement that mechanism for all in loop this script works correctly only for last one bar. Other bars not grooving.

My JS code below:

```html
  var foo = document.getElementById('chart-bars');
  var width;
  var elem;
  var id;
  for (var i = 0; i < foo.children.length; i++) {

   elem = foo.children[i].children[0];

     width = 1;
     id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= elem.dataset.percent) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        width++; 
        elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      }
    }

  }
```

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because value of `i` is out of scope of setInterval callback, setInterval takes only last value of iteration as it is a `window` method. So, you have to go with the closure or solution like this.

```
    var foo = document.querySelectorAll(".chart-bar");
    var width;
    var elem;
    var id;
    for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {

        var myElem = {
            x: i
        }

        width = 1;
        id = setInterval(function() {
            if (width >= foo[this.x].dataset.percent) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                width++;
                foo[this.x].style.width = width + '%';
            }
        }.bind(myElem), 10);//Here you are binding that setInterval should run on the myElem object context not window context

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations!  Today will learn what a "closure" is.

You are experiencing a scoping issue.  The reason this only works for the last bar is because the `frame` function only sees `elem` *as it currently exists on scope*.  That is to say, by the time your `setInterval` runs your loop will have ended and `elem` will be firmly set to what amounts to `foo.children[foo.children.length - 1].children[0]`

The way to fix this is by creating a new closure.  That is to say, you "close" the variable in a scope.

```
var foo = document.getElementById('chart-bars');

for (var i = 0; i < foo.children.length; i++) {
  (function (elem, width) {
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= elem.dataset.percent) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        width++; 
        elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      }
    }
  })(foo.children[i].children[0], 1)
}
```

now this, specifically, is a far from perfect way of accomplishing your goal, but I wrote it this way in order to preserve as much of your code as possible in an attempt to reduce the cognitive load for your specific example.

Essentially what I am doing is wrapping your code in an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), which creates a new scope with your `elem` and `width` variables fixed to that function's scope.

A further step in the right direction would be to pull your `frame` function outside of the loop and have it only created once and have it accept as its arguments an `elem`, `width`, and `id` parameter, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the specific jquery lybraries to create the charts like morrischart or chartjs, there are very simple and they work very well
there are the documentations
http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/
https://www.chartjs.org

Comment: Because I dont have control on all aspects. I was trying implement chart JS and i have problem with clicable labels, wraping labels, tooltip customisation, mobile RWD etc

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a variable scope issue, could you try something like this :

```
var foo = document.getElementById('chart-bars');
for (var i = 0; i < foo.children.length; i++) {

   var elem = foo.children[i].children[0];
   elem.style.width = '1%';

   var id = setInterval(function() { frame(elem, id) }, 10);
}

function frame(elem, idInterval) {
   var width = parseInt(elem.style.width);
   if (width >= elem.dataset.percent) {
     clearInterval(idInterval);
   } else {
     width++; 
     elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
   }
}
```

Basically before you were erasing at each loop your previous elem, width, and id variables because they were declared outside the for loop. Hence the weird behavior.

Edit : putting the frame function outside so that it's clearer.

Edit2 : removing width from frame function as it is not needed.